# KDE Connect - Main phone and Desktop cant see each other - Second phone can see both my Main phone and Desktop

Tags: android, connection, debian, phone, kde-connect

I was trying to set up KDE Connect on my Debian with KDE Plasma and my Main phone, however they could not see each other. Because of that I spent quite a lot of time dealing with the issue and ran through many discussions online about the issue (Setting up the firewall properly, different versions, etc.). However nothing helped.

Later I decided to KDE Connect on my other phone that I do not use nor intend to use. After launching the app I was able to see both my Main phone and my Desktop from it and connect to both of them. So my only guess is that there is an issue with either my Main phone or the app itself.

Just to be clear, both phones are Android phones and run the same version of the app `1.14.2`

- **Main phone:**  `Honor 8 lite / Android 8.0.0` (can see only second phone)
- **Second phone:** `Samsung Galaxy J5(2016) / Android 7.1.1` (can see both man phone and desktop)

Comment: I have the same issue with KDE Connect: my desktop (Ubuntu 20.04, KDE Connect 1.4-0ubuntu5) and my Android Device (Onyx Boox Max, Android 4.1, KDE Connect 1.14.2) can't see each other, while other devices can see both of them. This issue started after an upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04. Before the update everything was working fine. I don't know how to fix it.